# readthedocs, local instance, building documentation never concludes

Tags: python, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I started with fresh install of readthedocs.org:

http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Next I have added SocialApp GitHub in admin panel and then connected my superuser to that GitHub account.

Then I went to github and I forked readthedocs repository.

https://github.com/Drachenfels/Test-Fork

Next I clicked import projects. Task never concludes but when I refresh page, repos are there.

I picked forked repository Test-Fork and I clicked build.

Task never finishes, when I refresh or start another one, they are stuck in state "Triggered". There is no error, nothing.

What is more I am default configuration of readthedocs.

I have running in the background following processes:

```
./manager.py runserver 9000
./manage.py celerdybeat --verbosity=3
./manage.py celeryd -E
./manage.py celercycam
redis-server
```

Do I miss anything at this point?

It looks like for me that despite having celery active and running tasks are never initiated nor killed, nor errored.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was not with celery, tasks were running eagerly (what I was suspecting but not really sure), so as soon as they triggered they were executed.

Problem was that task responsible for building documentation (update_docs) was failing silently. Thus state 'Triggering' never concluded and build was never initiated. It happens that this error was my own fault I run django server on different port than it's in default settings. Exception was thrown, it was never logged, state of task was never updated, readthedocs was left in the limbo. I hope it will help some lost souls out there.